# my loop changes all values to the last element

Tags: javascript

why does my for loop change all values of an array to the same thing?

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = otherarr[i];
}
```

it changes all values in arr to the last element in otherarr when it finishes.
they have the same length.
Im new to programming, can anybody help me?

im making a Knight's tour and when i press a button i want it to show a possible way to complete it.

```
var rightmoves = ["e8", "g7", "h5", "f6", "e4", "g3", "h1", "f2", "d1", "b2", "a4", "c3", "d5", "b6", "a8", "c7", "b5", "a7", "c8", "d6", "c4", "a3", "b1", "d2", "f1", "h2", "g4", "e3", "f5", "h6", "g8", "e7", "c6", "d8", "b7", "a5", "b3", "a1", "c2", "d4", "f3", "e1", "g2", "h4", "g6", "h8", "f7", "g5", "h7", "f8", "e6", "f4", "h3", "g1", "e2", "c1", "a2", "b4", "d3", "c5", "a6", "b8", "d7", "e5"];
for (var i = 0; i < rightmoves.length; i++) {
    moves[i] = knight;
    moves[i].row = rightmoves[i].charAt(1);
    console.log(moves[i].row)
}
```

knight has properties like the row and col where its at on the chessboard, and moves stores the moves it does.
when i look at moves in console in chrome moves has 64 objects, all of them have the same value for row, but the console log put all the correct values of the row in.

Comment: what data is inside your arr, and otherarr?

Comment: This code should do exactly what you expect it to, so there's something else wrong. What makes you think it sets all values in `arr` to the last in `otherarr`? Post some of the code before and after this loop to demonstrate the complete error.

Comment: Did you set `arr = otherarr` at some point in the code?

Comment: SO is a _terrible_ debugger. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the same object reference `knight` into each index of array.

Try pushing a shallow copy instead by using [`Object#assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) so you have unique objects in each index of the array

```
for (var i = 0; i < rightmoves.length; i++) {
    moves[i] = Object.assign({},knight);// shallow copy of knight object
    moves[i].row = rightmoves[i].charAt(1);
    console.log(moves[i].row)
}
```